# HttpListener seems to lose connection after a period of time

Tags: c#, .net, https, tcplistener, httplistener

I'm fairly new to C# programming, and I'm trying to interact with a program that provides an interface for sending data over uri. So far this works great, but after approximately 1-2mins the program is still sending data but my console apllication doesn't recognize it anymore.

Btw this is my first Question on stackoverflow so please be patient :)

The program has a field to enter the uri of a webserver where status updates of the program are send to in json format. There I've entered the IP of the Computer where my console application is running (2 different Computers). In case of the configuration of the external program that should be all.

Now regarding my console application:

For testing purposes the app only writes the timesamp of the recieved json in the console and everythings works Pretty well, until at some point the console doesn't Show new entrys althougth in the sender program I can see that new statuses are created. I've monitored the connection with Wireshark and everthing seems to be normal, expect after the named issue Wireshark shows no more traffic. 
If I Restart one of the applications with the other one still running and then start the other one again, it works again for 1-2mins.

If there are any other things you need to know, just let me know.

```
private static readonly HttpListener Listener = new HttpListener();
```

**Main**

```
        // Specified password and username for basic http authentification
        pass.SetValue("LKGsgcxSXh", 0);
        pass.SetValue("r0QNdbqJCdPz3WdpSRqi", 1);

        Listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic;
        HttpListenerTimeoutManager manager;
        manager = Listener.TimeoutManager;
        manager.IdleConnection = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);


        Listener.Prefixes.Add("https://+:443/api/");
        Listener.Start();
        Listen();
        Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

**private static async void Listen()**

```
        while (true)
        {
            var context = await Listener.GetContextAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Client connected");
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessRequest(context));
        }

        Listener.Close();
```

**private static void ProcessRequest(HttpListenerContext context)**

```
        HttpListenerBasicIdentity identity = (HttpListenerBasicIdentity)context.User.Identity;
        HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;

        if (identity.Name == pass[0] && identity.Password == pass[1])
        {

            // Get a stream object for reading and writing
            using (Stream stream = request.InputStream)
            {
                Encoding encoding = request.ContentEncoding;
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding))
                {
                 ´// Processing the json and write the timestamp
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unauthorized access");
        }
```